# How is T(2) == T(1) different from std::is_same_v<T, bool> for integral types T?

Tags: c++, libstdc++

I would like to ensure that an integral type is not `bool` in `static_assert`. I found in the source code of libstdc++ that it uses `_Mn(2) != _Mn(1)` for this purpose:

```cpp
  template<typename _Mn, typename _Nn>
    constexpr common_type_t<_Mn, _Nn>
    gcd(_Mn __m, _Nn __n) noexcept
    {
      static_assert(is_integral_v<_Mn>, "std::gcd arguments must be integers");
      static_assert(is_integral_v<_Nn>, "std::gcd arguments must be integers");
      static_assert(_Mn(2) != _Mn(1), "std::gcd arguments must not be bool"); // HERE
      static_assert(_Nn(2) != _Nn(1), "std::gcd arguments must not be bool");
      using _Up = make_unsigned_t<common_type_t<_Mn, _Nn>>;
      return __detail::__gcd(__detail::__absu<_Up>(__m),
                 __detail::__absu<_Up>(__n));
    }
```

It seems that libstdc++ is intentionally avoiding the more apparent form `!is_same_v<_Mn, bool>`. How are the two forms different? Which one should I use for the same purpose?

---

@KamilCuk pointed out that `_Mn(2) != _Mn(1)` was once `!is_same_v<remove_cv_t<_Mn>, bool>` in libstdc++. ([Commit](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/82db1a42e9254c9009bbf8ac01366da4d1ab6df5))

Comment: Maybe `is_same_v` is not available at that point (or they don't want that dependencies)?...

Comment: one is standard the other is an implementation detail

Comment: From compilation **micro** performance point of view, `_Mn(2) == _Mn(1)`  doesn't instantiate template class (so one less instantiation).

Comment: @Jarod42 That's weird. `std::is_same_v` was introduced together with `std::is_integral_v`, which is used just above the line I quoted.

Comment: _" it uses `_Mn(2) != _Mn(1)` for this purpose"_ - Not only. That check alone isn't worth much without the `is_integral_v` check above as @463035818_is_not_a_number points out below.

Comment: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/82db1a42e9254c9009bbf8ac01366da4d1ab6df5 It was `!is_same_v<remove_cv_t<_Mn>, bool>`, but I do not see clear explanation for the change.

Comment: I wouldn't exclude the simple possibility that the code has been maintained over time by different developers, who each have different preferences when using (even experimenting with) different ways of coding a solution to the same problem.   Which amounts to different techniques being used for subjective reasons, rather than technical ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is only one type that passes the `is_integral_v<_Mn>` assert but would fail the `_Mn(1) == _Mn(2)` check, and that is `bool`. The check is ok to identify `bool` in this special circumstance, when only types that are `std::integral_v == true` are considered.

Note that `_Mn(1) == _Mn(2)` can detect and cv variant of `bool`, hence the right comparison is `std::is_same_v<std::remove_cv_t<Mn>,bool>` (Thanks to Jarod42 to point that out).

However, when not considering only `std::integral_v == true` the `_Mn(1) == _Mn(2)` check is not sufficient to know that it is `bool` or not. It could be any other type.

When you want to know if two types are the same you should use `std::is_same`.

---

PS: In general I do not advise to learn how to write C++ code from the implementation of the standard library. By no means it is bad code, but it is code that lives in a different domain. Most notably, things that are undefined in user code can be completely fine in the implementation (as for example identifiers like `_Mn`).

Comment: As other answer points out, cv variant of bool also fails `_Mn(1) == _Mn(2)`, and `!std::is_same_v<bool, _Mn>` test should be `!std::is_same_v<std::remove_cv_t<_Mn>, bool>` as found in history.

Comment: @Jarod42 right added it to the answer

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that cv-qualified non-reference `bool` types (`const bool`, `volatile bool` and `const volatile bool`) pass `std::is_integral_v<T> && !std::is_same_v<T, bool>` but fail `std::is_integral_v<T> && T(2) == T(1)`. `std::remove_cv_t<T>` should be used instead of `T` in `std::is_same_v` to handle these types correctly.